# High speed IR connection

Tags: fpga, infrared, high-speed

Are there any IR receivers/transmitters with speed higher then **4Mbps**?
As I found most parts are limited to **4Mbps**, like **LT1328** (photodiode receiver) and **TFBS6711** (infrared transceiver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are. The IrDA (particularly, the IrPHY specification) has several levels of IR speeds, which use different modulation schemes. You just have to google a transceiver that supports the modulation speed that you want:

```
SIR: 9.6–115.2 kbit/s
MIR: 0.576–1.152 Mbit/s
FIR: 4 Mbit/s, 4PPM
VFIR: 16 Mbit/s
UFIR: 96 Mbit/s
GigaIR: 512 Mbit/s – 1 Gbit/s
```

The first link google shows on "IrDA VFIR transceiver" is Vishay TFDU8108:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/82558/tfdu8108.pdf

Since this is a VFIR transceiver, it must support the 16Mbps connection. The transceivers that you've found are FIR transceivers, which means 4Mbps speed.

UFIR and GigaIR transceivers are way more exotic and rare.